Amazon S3 as Source for Apache Flink using CDC
I need to publish the event using CDC whenever a file is added to S3, to Apache Flink, from Flink the newly added file has to be read and processed.

you can receive notifications when s3:ObjectCreated:* events happen in your S3 bucket, implement your own Data Source just like io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource, then process it.
